# Width 100% footer in a non responsive site

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have to fix the footer in a non-responsive site.

All the content (but the footer) is placed in a CSS declaration called ".centrado". It has a fixed width:

```
  .centrado{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1170px;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
   }
```

I need a footer with a width of 100%. It works in desktops but not in mobiles. The CSS for the footer is:

```
.pie_de_sitio{
   float:left; 
   width: 100%;
   height:auto;
   display:flex;    
   overflow:hidden; 
   align-items: center; 
   justify-content: center;
   background:#333D4C;
   padding:25px 0 25px 0;   
   margin: 50px 0 0 0;  
   bottom: 0;
}
```

In mobiles I'm getting a white space in the right side of the footer. That white space has a width of approximately 20% of the screen on mobiles.

Here is how the footer looks on mobiles:

[image: The Footer]

Thanks

Comment: Please create minimal example in SO Snippet with relevant HTML and CSS code. Possibly some wrapper has `overflow: hidden` and it cuts your content

Comment: Hi @Justinas
I did check this possibility before asking here, without success.

Comment: We can't tell anything from your image. Inspect elements and see if there is some parent of such size. If so, check why it is like that

Comment: Can you provide html?

Answer (score 0):

Try to divide the full website into section and add each section into `container` or `container-fluid` class.
***Note**: Make sure to keep the footer on `container-fluid` class.*

After that start fixing the responsiveness from top to bottom and inspect the website and check which section is overflowing, the  your footer will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:left` property for mobile, make it none and try, and adjust width accordingly. Try writing media query for better understanding. Let me know if this doesn't work for you.